# Creating a table on the basis of a field

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a MySql table which has about 100k rows. there is one field say id which contains numbers from 1-35. all these records fall in this range of id i.e. all these records have value of id column between 1-35.

Now i want to create another table which will have one row of each id. i.e the new table should have 35 rows only.

How to go about it ?

Comment: So you want to copy all rows from a table with a specific value to a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table new_table (id int);
insert into new_table
    select distinct id from big_table;
```

### Edit:

You can create the `new_table` by outputting the `big_table` create script and changing the name.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE big_table;
/* modify the name of the output and execute */
insert into new_table
    select * from big_table group by id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But by this method, I can get the value of only id field. I want all the fields of the big_table but only once. for eg. if the id with value 1 has 10k fields, i want only one of these in new_table similarly for id with value 2 and so on. Is there a way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table with 100.000 rows, and you want a new table with 35 rows. What values do you want for the remaining columns?

If the answer is: doesn't matter, this works:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT * FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you only want the IDs,

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Actually, I want just these 35 rows in the new table and don't want any other row. That's the main issue I am struggling with. Is there a way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data from one table to another even difference database(Schema) as following

```
INSERT INTO [DestDatabase].[DestTablName]
SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [SourceDatabase].[SourceTablName];
```

So, you can use two way:

1:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_New
SELECT DISTINCT id from tbl_Original;
```

2:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_New
SELECT id from tbl_Original GROUP BY id;
```